# Extra page at beginning of appendix containing big figures

Tags: spacing, floats, positioning, appendices

I have an appendix that contains two full-page figures.  The first page of the appendix is always blank except for the title -- I suspect this is a common problem with appendices of full page figures.

I narrowed the problem down to a MWE that, as it turns out can be reproduced without appendices at all.  Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Big Figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Big Figure}
    \includegraphics[height=0.76\vsize, width=0.4\hsize]{foo.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Clearly there is enough room to fit this on a single page.

Changing to `height=0.75` yields

[image]

Note the excessive white space below the figure.

What is going on here?  Why can't this figure be bigger without creating a second page?

Answer (score 10):

Since your image must go in a precise location, it doesn't make much sense to use a floating environment; use a `minipage` and `\captionof` (from the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages) to provide the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\section{Big Figure}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionof{figure}{Big Figure}
    \includegraphics[height=0.76\vsize, width=0.4\hsize]{foo.png}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this approach somehow fundamentally different from using `{figure}[h!]`?  Don't both approaches essentially mean "put this box _here_"?  It's not clear to me when you would use one versus the other.

Comment: @alx9r yes, both approaches are essentially different (although the resulting document might look the same in some cases, as in this particular little exmaple); my approach treats the image in a non-floating way. On the other hand, using `\begin{figure}[!h]...\end{figure}` (which, by the way, is so restrictive that it should be avoided, if possible, and in fact, it's internally changed to `[!ht]`) still treats the object as a floating object, but overrides values controlling its possible positions; you can see the difference in a real document with some text.

Comment: @alx9r A mandatory reference here (to understand flotation and its ways) is Frank Mittelbach's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/3954

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that answer in my search.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Big Figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \caption{Big Figure}
    \includegraphics[height=0.76\vsize, width=0.4\hsize]{foo.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives the desired output (`[h]` is replaced by `[h!]`). It overrides maximal and minimal values of floats and text.